# Binding ComboBox MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is the first time I try to bind combobox. I'm trying get  values from my database. However, with the code below, I'm getting this as a result (the same number of results as the rows count of my table):

> GUITest.DB.Structure

where GUITest -> namespace of my project, DB -> folder where structure.cs is.

```
private ObservableCollection<Structure> _lists;
    public ObservableCollection<Structure> Lists
    {
        get { return _lists; }
        set
        {
            _lists = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Lists");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Structure> GetStructures()
    {
       ObservableCollection<Structure> products  = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
        using (SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringConnexion"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdNotes =
                new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Structure", conn);


            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdNotes.ExecuteReader())
            {

                var ordinals = new
                {
                    CodeStr = reader.GetOrdinal("CODE_STR"),
                    NomStr = reader.GetOrdinal("NOM_STR"),

                };

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    var temp = new TableStructure();

                    temp.CodeStr = reader.GetString(ordinals.CodeStr);
                    temp.NomStr = reader.GetString(ordinals.NomStr);

                    products.Add(temp.SqlProduct2Product());
                }
            }
        }
        return products;  
    }

    public CreateAccountViewModel()
    {
        _lists = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
        Lists = GetStructures();
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=NomStr}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}"></ComboBox>
```

Comment: Seems you want to show the NomStr property value in the CaomboBox. Set `DisplayMemberPath="NomStr"`. To bind SelectedItem (or SelectedValue) there should be an appropriate property in your view model class, i.e. te class thathas the `Lists` property. As a note, you don't need to assign a value to `_lists` immideately before you assign `Lists`.

Comment: I did that but never worked at first but now it did, I guess it's because of the Binding keywoard, why it's not necessary in this case?

Also, I'm loading this from the database so the user could insert the CodeStr later, should I bind CodeStr to SelectedItem in that case? thank you!

Comment: [How to: Bind to a Collection and Display Information Based on Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-a-collection-and-display-information-based-on-selection).

Comment: what error you are getting in Output window?

Comment: The issue has been fixed as I mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you want `DisplayMemberPath` not `SelectedItem`

`DisplayMemberPath` says "Display this property (as a path) as the *ItemTemplate*" it is functionally equivalent (though *not* code equivalent) to, for a path of X:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=X}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate
</ComboBox>
```

This is why you don't have the `Binding` extension in it, the framework puts it in for you.

`SelectedItem` is just that, the current selection of the combo box. It doesn't affect the display in any way.

Comment: I managed to get NomStr displayed. How about CodeStr? My understanding is that I should bind "CodeStr" to SelectedItem? so whenever the NomStr changes, the CodeStr will change with it? (CodeStr should not be visible for the user)

Comment: @Csharpnewbie `SelectedItem` should be bound to a property on the VM (*not* the items) that *holds* the current selection. If you want that *value* to be the `CodeStr` of that item you use `SelectedMemberPath` IIRC; though I usually just bind to a reference to the actual item and then pull out whatever properties I need.

Comment: Yes I realize that! so It's SelectedMemberPath, thank you!